# Passing an specific error python

Tags: python-2.7, exception

I am trying to pass a specific key error.by this two.

```
try:    
    per_visit_large_store = 100 * dic_data[mac]['Retail Store']['No. of visit to large store']/float(dic_data[mac]['Total no. of walk_in'])
except KeyError: 'Retail Store'
    pass
```

and

```
try:    
    per_visit_large_store = 100 * dic_data[mac]['Retail Store']['No. of visit to large store']/float(dic_data[mac]['Total no. of walk_in'])
except KeyError: 'Retail Store':
    pass
```

both of this raises Indentation and syntax error respectively. What exactly I am doing wrong? I am using python 2.7

Comment: Are you trying to only catch the KeyError if the key is 'Retail Store'?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
try:
    # some code there
except KeyError as e:
    caused_key = e.args[0]
    if caused_key == 'Retail Store':
        pass
```

See more in [Python Exception tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

**Good Luck :)!**

Comment: Will this one pass all the key error or specifically one with `'Retail Store` ??

Comment: @ranadan this would pass all key errors

Comment: well I was looking for specific one :)

Comment: @ranadan see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
try:
    ...
except KeyError:
    pass
```

---

If you want to catch a specific key then you need to check the message of the error:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
try:
    d['c']
except KeyError as e:
    if e.message == 'c':
        blah
    else:
        raise KeyError, e
```

This will only continue the code if the key is 'c'. If it is not, then the error is raised.

Comment: That will pass all the key errors I want to pass thi specific one.

Comment: HOw exactly wait I am putting my try part too.

Comment: @ranadan Wait I misinterpreted: Check my answer now